# Add rows based on the numerical value of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I may be going about this the wrong way, but they way I plan to analyze my data I will need one entry for each application.

My data frame looks something like this:

```
ID   Job Title  Number Applied  Hired  Feature(Math)
 1  Accountant               3      2              1
 2   Marketing               1      1              0
 3     Finance               1      1              1
```

I need to make it look like this (1 = yes, 0 = no):

```
ID   Job Title  Number Applied  Hired  Feature(Math)       
 1  Accountant               1      0              1
 2  Accountant               1      1              1
 3  Accountant               1      1              1
 4   Marketing               1      1              0
 5     Finance               1      1              1
```

I need to add a row for each person who applied. `Number Applied` should always be 1. Once this is complete we can drop the `Number Applied` column.

There are additional features I did not include. The point of the analysis is to apply a machine learning algorithm to predict if a person will find a job based on their skill set. My current data frame does not work because when I convert hired to yes or no, it thinks only 2 people with math skills were hired instead of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I've used previously to "unroll" a set of aggregated samples.

```
from itertools import imap, izip

def iterdicts(df):
    """
    Utility to iterate over rows of a data frame as dictionaries.
    """
    col = df.columns
    for row in df.itertuples(name=None, index=False):
        yield dict(zip(col, row))

def deaggregate(dicts, *columns):
    """
    Deaggregate an iterable of dictionaries `dicts` where the numbers in `columns`
    are assumed to be aggregated counts.
    """
    for row in dicts:
        for i in xrange(max(row[c] for c in columns)):
            d = dict(row)

            # replace each count by a 0/1 indicator
            d.update({c: int(i < row[c]) for c in columns})
            yield d

def unroll(df, *columns):
    return pd.DataFrame(deaggregate(iterdicts(df), *columns))
```

You can then do

```
unroll(df, 'Number Applied', 'Hired')
```

```
   Feature(Math)  Hired  ID   Job Title  Number Applied
0              1      1   1  Accountant               1
1              1      1   1  Accountant               1
2              1      0   1  Accountant               1
3              0      1   2   Marketing               1
4              1      1   3     Finance               1
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked like a charm. I wish I had come up with a solution as elegant as this on my own.

Comment: No problem. If one of the posted answers worked for you, please accept it (click the checkmark below the answer score).

Comment: @Srule You can also up-vote with your new reputation greater than 15... read [**WhatToDo**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Number Applied'])]

hired = (
    d1.groupby('Job Title').cumcount() >=
        d1['Number Applied'] - d1['Hired']
).astype(int)

d1.assign(**{'Number Applied': 1, 'Hired': hired})

   ID   Job Title  Number Applied  Hired  Feature(Math)
0   1  Accountant               1      0              1
0   1  Accountant               1      1              1
0   1  Accountant               1      1              1
1   2   Marketing               1      1              0
2   3     Finance               1      1              1
```

Comment: Apologies!  No time to explain.